# Cloud Spanner max number of DatabaseClient

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Is there a maximum number of `DatabaseClient` that can be created for an instance of Google Cloud Spanner?

Will the number of `DatabaseClient` affect to the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DatabaseClients are cached, so for identical database ids `Spanner#getDatabaseClient` returns the same instance of `DatabaseClient`.

Internally `DatabaseClient` opens multiple gRPC channels and maintains the session pool. This is something that can be configured with [SpannerOptions#setNumChannels](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.9.3/apidocs/com/google/cloud/spanner/SpannerOptions.Builder.html#setNumChannels-int-) and [SpannerOptions#setSessionPoolOptions](http://SpannerOptions#setSessionPoolOptions).

The default number of open channels is optimized for low latency requests and works well in most cases. If you are sending high latency requests increasing number of channels potentially can lead to better throughput.

Comment: Actually, i never touch the SpannerOptions. I just follow the simple tutorial written on Spanner documentaion. Well, I will give it a try, and let you know how it goes. thanks anyway !

Sorry for late reply.